# NSURLConnection didFinishLoading is executed after a long time

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am developing an apps in which is using an API. There is already an apps out there in the app store that utilizes this API end point as well. However, the issue is that apps is more snappier than mine, I am pretty sure that he didn't implement any caching as loading new data that I haven't visited is still fast. We're basically calling the same API, but his took less than a second to load while my took 2-5 seconds for the didFinishLoading delegate to be triggered. There is basic authentication in the apps. How is this possible?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSURL * url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://convore.com/api/groups.json"];
    NSMutableURLRequest * URLRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", @"user", @"pass"];

    NSData *encodeData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    char encodeArray[512];

    memset(encodeArray, '\0', sizeof(encodeArray));

    // Base64 Encode username and password
    encode([encodeData length], (char *)[encodeData bytes], sizeof(encodeArray), encodeArray);

    //authStr = [NSString stringWithCString:encodeArray length:strlen(encodeArray)];
    authStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:encodeArray];
    NSString * auth_string = [@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"Basic %@", authStr];

    [URLRequest addValue:auth_string forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    startInterval = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSURLConnection * connection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:URLRequest delegate:self] retain];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"RESPONSE RECEIVED DATA");
    stopInterval = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    elapsedTime = stopInterval - startInterval;
    NSLog(@"ELAPSED TIME is %f", elapsedTime);
    NSString *string=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
    [string release];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response { 
    NSLog(@"RESPONSE RECEIVED");
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"RESPONSE FINISHED LOADING");
}
```

It print's out:

```
RESPONSE RECEIVED
RESPONSE RECEIVED DATA
ELAPSED TIME is 3.552402
RESPONSE FINISHED LOADING
```

Comment: Can you post some code and give a bit more detail about the API?

Comment: the api is from www.convore.com and with regards to code I will update above

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the bottleneck may be in your BASE64 encoder but I am not sure. I have a couple of suggestions:

First, since you're using SSL (https), you don't really need to encode the credentials (seems a bit overkill).

Second, try using the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions) library. It is more concise, and in my experience runs slightly faster than `NSURLConnection` library methods.

I got these results with the code below:

```
2011-06-10 17:30:28.564 MyApp[1773:903] Finished
2011-06-10 17:30:28.566 MyApp[1773:903] ELAPSED TIME is 0.599967
2011-06-10 17:30:28.566 MyApp[1773:903] {"groups": []}

NSTimeInterval startInterval, stopInterval, elapsedTime;

- (void)reqFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"Finished");
    stopInterval = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    elapsedTime = stopInterval - startInterval;
    NSLog(@"ELAPSED TIME is %f", elapsedTime);
    NSString *string = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}


- (void)reqFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"Failed with %d error: %@", [request responseStatusCode], [[request error] description]);
    stopInterval = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    elapsedTime = stopInterval - startInterval;
    NSLog(@"ELAPSED TIME is %f", elapsedTime);
    NSString *string = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);    
} 


- (void) getGroups
{
    NSURL * url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://convore.com/api/groups.json"];

    ASIHTTPRequest* request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-type" value:@"application/json"]; 
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"]; 

    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(reqFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(reqFailed:)];
    [request setDelegate:self]; 
    [request setUsername:@"username"];
    [request setPassword:@"password"];
    [request startAsynchronous];
    startInterval = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
}
```

Comment: are you saying that ASIHTTPRequest is slightly faster than NSURLConnection?

Comment: Actually it's approximately the same, but using ASIHTTPRequest is much more painless than using NSURLConnection.